# AWK: how to select lines by the number of words in one field?

Tags: text-processing, awk

Here's a text file I have:

```
1|this|1000
2|that|2000
3|hello|3000
4|hello world|4000
5|lucky you|5000
6|awk is awesome|6000
.
.
.
```

How do I only print the lines that have two and only two words (line 4 and 5) in the $2?

This is what I have tried but it counts the number of letters instead of words:

```
awk -F"|" '{if(length($2==2) print $0}'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the return value of the awk `split` function:

```
$ awk -F'|' 'split($2,a,"[ \t]+") == 2' file
4|hello world|4000
5|lucky you|5000
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use return value of `gsub` function instead.

```
awk -F'|' '{l=$0} gsub(/[ \t]+/,"",$2)==1{print l}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^.+\|\w+ \w+\|/' input.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- `'/^.+\|\w+ \w+\|/'` - all lines conforming this pattern will be printed.
- `^` - starting from the beginning of the line.
- `.+` - one or more any characters.
- `\|` - pipe character. Should be escaped by the backslash for perceiving literally, else it processed as 'or' sign.
- `\w+ \w+\` - any word characters, then space, then any word characters or, in other words: word space word - exactly, what you need.
- `\|` - the second pipe character.

**Input**

```
1|this|1000
2|that|2000
3|hello|3000
4|hello world|4000
5|lucky you|5000
6|awk is awesome|6000
```

**Output**

```
4|hello world|4000
5|lucky you|5000
```